# Universal quantifier manipulation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$$\forall x(\varphi\vee\psi)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad (\forall x\varphi)\vee \psi\qquad\qquad\text{if }x\notin\mathrm{FREE}(\psi)$$

This formula was written in our cheat sheet, and to me, it does not make sense. Suppose a sentence

$$\forall x(x+2=4 \,\lor\,x+10=8)$$

It is apparent that in the second part of the sentence, $x+10=8$, $x$ is not in the set of free variables of this part. It is in the set of bound variables. Therefore, according to the formula, we should be able to do this:

$$\forall x(x+2=4)\,\lor\,x+10=8$$

I don't think this is correct, as $x$ still needs to be bound to the quantifier. So what am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Every occurence of the letter $x$ inside the parentheses right after the quantifier is bound by the quantifier. One cannot change the formula as you did in your last line.

Comment: @coffeemath Why is the cheatsheet formula correct then?

Comment: The equiv on top of the post does not apply to your formula because x is free in the righe disjunct ( the psi).

Comment: In your formula, $psi$ is just the part $x+10=8,$ provided you correctly match your first general formula to it. However because of this, $x$ is a free vriable of $\psi.$ so the proviso at the right of your first formula is not in effect.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey key mathematical information. [See here for why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). What you wrote can be done in MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to the whole formula $\forall x (x+2=4 \lor x +10 = 8)$, $x$ is indeed a bound variable.

As such, $x \not \in FREE(\forall x (\phi \lor \psi))$

However, the formula $\psi$ *by itself* is $x +10=8$.

And relative to *that* formula, $x$ **is** free.

Thus: $x \in FREE(\psi)$

And that's why your move is blocked.